# I'm trying to add an attribute to a bunch of lines in a XML file with a regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to add an attribute Total to a bunch of lines in a XML file with a regex in Notepad++

Before :

```
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7500" Total="4764" Percentage="5.00"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7561" Total="1500" Percentage="1.73"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="1090" Percentage="10.00"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7530" Percentage="6.00"/>`
```

After :

```
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7500" Total="4764" Percentage="5.00"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7561" Total="1500" Percentage="1.73"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="1090" Total="0" Percentage="10.00"/>
<TaxAmount TaxCode="7530" Total="0" Percentage="6.00"/>`
```

I would like to include Total="0" when this attribute is missing after TaxCode

Comment: Why are you asking twice [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75987194/372239)

Comment: The first formulation wasn't correct

Comment: I was able to find the solution
Search : (<TaxAmount TaxCode="[^"]*")(?![^>]*Total=)
Replace : $1 Total="0"